# La construction "ne pas ..." est-elle récente?

Tags: grammaire, usage, histoire, injonctions

Souvent en français, on trouve des panneaux, ou bien sûr des personnes en autorité qui diraient "Ne pas ..." pour exprimer une interdiction; par exemple:

> Ne pas courir !
>   Ne pas monter dans le train sans billet.

Cette construction est-elle récente ?  C'est différent des autres négations, où on entoure le verbe avec "ne" et "pas"; ici, simplement on jette les mots en début de phrase.

Comment: C'est vrai qu'instinctivement, j'aurais marqué « Ne courez pas ! »…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ce n'est pas très différent des autres négations. Il s'agit simplement de la négation de l'infinitif, et la construction elle-même n'est certainement pas nouvelle.

En demandant quelques chiffres à *ngrams*, de façon intéressante, on voit que la négation de l'infinitif est de plus en plus utilisée :

[image: négation de l'infinitif]

Mais ce n'est pas facile de savoir si son utilisation dans les injonctions suit la même tendance. À titre de comparaison, l'emploi des infinitifs en général semble assez stable. Étrangement, on pourrait même penser que l'on se trouve dans une période un peu creuse :

[image: infinitifs]

Comment: Dommage que pour une fois, _être ou ne pas être_ n'était pas la question.

Answer (score 5):

Cette construction ne me semble pas récente. Du moins je l'ai toujours vu formulée de la sorte, ne serait-ce que sur les fenêtres de certains trains devant dater des années 60 ou 70: *ne pas se pencher par les fenêtres*.

J'ai cherché sans succès des sources plus anciennes sur internet. Si j'en trouve, je ne manquerai pas d'éditer cette réponse.

Answer (score 4):

La négation se place toujours en bloc devant un infinitif. Voir au hasard [ici](http://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-72042.php) et [là](http://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-72042.php).

Quant à l'usage d'un infinitif plutôt qu'un impératif, je pense qu'il faut simplement y voir une volonté de politesse, de la même manière que « veuillez vous asseoir » est préféré à « asseyez-vous! ». Et, bien entendu, la partie « veuillez » n'apportant pas grand chose, elle est d'autant plus volontiers sacrifiée.

Ne pas voir dans cette réponse une vérité absolue.

Comment: C'est plutôt un commentaire qu'une réponse à la question, non ?

Comment: Je vois ça comme une réponse, à part bien entendu le fait que j'aborde pas le sujet du « quand », mais je pense que je sous-entends bien que c'est une construction suffisamment valide que pour considérer qu'elle n'est pas un néologisme.

Answer (score 0):

La SNCF aimait effectivement bien poser devant chaque fenêtre de voiture la fameuse inscription en quatre langues : « Ne pas se pencher au dehors – Do not lean out of the window – Nichr hinauslehnen – E pericoloso sporgersi » ; je cite de mémoire, ne pas m'en vouloir en cas de petite inexactitude.

Rien de récent en tout cas, ni de choquant.