# What is the construction used in negating with "ne pas" (but not ne..pas)?

Tags: négation, infinitif, constructions

I am in in Québec City for a five day vacation. One sentence I entered into google translate is "I regret not studying French more", and google translate gave me the following:

> Je regrette de ne pas étudier plus français.

I don't understand the usage of "ne pas".

I tried researching in three places. The first two places were looking in the "negation" grammar section of my two favourite websites for learning French: Lawless French (at https://www.lawlessfrench.com/tag/negation/), and Tex's French grammar (at https://www.laits.utexas.edu/tex/gr/neg2.html), but in both sections, "ne pas" was never talked about (although "ne .. pas" was talked about).

On this French Stackexchange website, one webpage ([La construction "ne pas ..." est-elle récente?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1443/la-construction-ne-pas-est-elle-r%C3%A9cente)) gives me the idea that "ne pas" is used to negate an infinitive, but I'm not 100% sure I understand what that page is saying.

Can someone recommend to me a website in English that talks explicitly about "ne pas" and how it is used? Or, can someone tell me comprehensively this information here?

Comment: @Legomononc'bléd'Ingres, I am curious to hear what a better translation (or a better source English sentence) would be here!

Comment: I thought using "further" instead of _more_, and changing the verb construction (_not having studied_ etc.) would yield something better, but no. Using "the French language" will make sure you get an article i.e. _la langue française_ (more generally _le français_). Consider _je regrette de_ (rare without) _ne pas avoir eu l'occasion d'étudier davantage la langue française avant mon séjour_ or _je regrette de ne pas avoir su/pu étudier davantage cette langue avant ma visite._ (respect. _failing at_  and _not having been able to_, study...)... amongst many (with _connaître_, _parler_, etc.).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Ne pas* + infinitive = *Not* + infinitive

where you can employ an *infinitive*, you can employ *ne pas + infinitive* : as subject, COD, COI, CC, ...

**except if you already have a negation:** 
*sans manger* => *sans ne pas manger* : **impossible**

*pas* is generally before the verbe, but can be put after the verb also:

- *n'y prendre pas part* ou *ne pas y prendre part* (with pronoun)
- *n'avoir pas lu* or *ne pas avoir lu* (with auxiliary)

You have another constructions like that (before or after the verbe):

- ne plus = not anymore
- ne jamais = never
- ne guère = not much

Comment: this was exactly the comprehensive answer i was looking for. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You're right, *ne pas* is used in front of an infinitive. I don't have a lesson dedicated to it because it's really that simple - there's nothing else to say. I mention it under word order in this lesson: https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/infinitive/

Comment: oh, i see. thanks for pointing this out.