# Does `ne` and `pas` have a different meaning?

Tags: négation

```
Pas de problème.
```

Means: No problem.
Here we are using `pas` do describe `not`.

```
Roksana a seize ans et elle ne va plus au lycée depuis deux semaines.
```

Means: Roksana is 16 years old and she not going more to the high school since two weeks.
Here we are using `ne` do describe `not`.

```
Est-ce que c’est difficile de ne pas sortir ?
```

Means: Is it difficult to not go out?
Here we are using `ne pas` to describe `not`.

```
Je ne veux pas
```

Means: I don't want
Here we are using `ne` before the verb `veux` and `pas` after the verb `veux` do describe `don't`.

**Question**

Does `ne` and `pas` have a different meaning?
Can I say that `ne = not` and `pas = no` and `ne <verb> pas = don't`?

Comment: I would say that 'pas' in "pas de probleme" could be replaced by "aucun" (no). But when in "je ne veux pas", you cannot separate it from the "ne" and the verbe as the purpose here is to negate the statement "je veux".

Comment: @OznOg So all verbs need to habe `ne` and `pas`? But when isin't a verb, then I can use 'ne'?

Comment: Actually, `ne` and `pas` should almost always be used together. Using `pas` alone to negate a verb is not grammatically correct (but very often used in casual conversations). You can say "Je ne vais y aller", this is correct and even quite "very formal". Do you have an example where you would like to use `ne` alone without verb?

Answer (score 1):

There is no much point trying to find a specific meaning or direct match with an English word for these adverbs.

***Ne*** and ***pas*** are used in negative statements, either alone or combined.

You translation of *elle ne va plus au lycée depuis...* by "she not going more to the high school" is weird. I'd rather expect: "she hasn't gone to the high school for..."

Anyway, formal French generally uses a split negative ***ne*** + another adverb like ***pas*** while spoken/casual French often drops the ***ne*** : *elle va plus au lycée depuis...*

See also:

[Quelle-est-la-différence-entre-ne-ne-pas-et-pas](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6604/quelle-est-la-diff%C3%A9rence-entre-ne-ne-pas-et-pas)

[What is the construction used in negating with "ne pas" (but not ne..pas)?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/17196/what-is-the-construction-used-in-negating-with-ne-pas-but-not-ne-pas)

[Ne pas, ne point, ne goutte](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/34748/ne-pas-ne-point-ne-goutte)

[Why does French use a "split negative"?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/884/why-does-french-use-a-split-negative)